# Andriod Studio Gradle - failed to resolve dagger any version over 2.24

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dagger

Here is the following snippet from the Gradle build file:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:${versions.dagger}"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:${versions.dagger}"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:${versions.dagger}"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${versions.dagger}"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:${versions.dagger}"
```

If I set the `${versions.dagger}` to anything over `2.24` e.g. `2.25.x` the gradle sync fails to resolve.
`ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.25.2`

**EDIT**: I checked the maven repository and the latest version available is `2.25.4`
**EDIT**: Upgrading from `2.24`